# Simplify ajax Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I have this function to write the inputs from a form to the database and i'm trying to simplify the data being passed by the ajax call to the php. Currently i have this function:

```
function writeDB(stage){
    var userData = $("#cacheDB").find("input").get();
    var ajaxData = []
    for (var n=0;n < userData.length; n++){
        item = {};
        item[userData[n].id] = userData[n].value;
        ajaxData.push(item);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "x.php",
        data: {ajaxData},
    });
}
```

Which sends out this object:

```
http://url.php?ajaxData[0][pageid]=1&ajaxData[1][input1]=John&ajaxData[2][input2]=Doe
```

I would like to send only the original data key, like:

```
http://url.php?[pageid]=1&[input1]=John&[input2]=Doe
```

Or

```
http://url.php?pageid=1&input1=John&input2=Doe
```

Is it posible? I've tried several methods and havn't found one suitable yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to serialize the form instead of that for loop. It basically sends all input fields from your form as a JSON object to the server.

```
$.post('server.php', $('#theForm').serialize())
```

For larger form, HTTP POST method should be prefferd, you can send complicated object.

Check this for more help: [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Hope its what you need.

Comment: The problem is that the inputs dont have names, only ids, and serialize returns a empty fieldset

Comment: And what is limiting you to add input also names..I would say its a good practice to have them, they are basically designed to be there for that purpose